# Strange image behavior in Today Extension iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, today-extension

I've always experienced strange behaviors with images in Today Extensions but this one is a new one. Once the widget area is revealed I have a button with an image that shows it like if it were disabled, but as soon as the widget loads the image is correctly loaded:

This is how the image is shown while I'm starting to reveal the widget area:

[image]

And here it is as soon as the widget is loaded:

[image]

But this doesn't happen using any other image. Using another one is perfectly shown while the widget area is being revealed and the alpha is always 1.0.

Have you ever experienced anything similar? I'm almost sure that the problem is the image but I've tried changing the name or adding it again to the project but nothing worked. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this looks like the system default when a button has been disabled. Perhaps try making the button type `custom` rather than `system` to see what happens, if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi Callam. Button type is already custom :/